# Are the tags "etimologia", "origem-histórica" and "origem" synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What do you think about these three tags:

- [etimologia](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimologia)
- [origem-histórica](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origem-hist%c3%b3rica)
- [origem](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origem)

Are they synonymous? Why?